# Playframework templates getting started

Tags: scala, intellij-idea, playframework

I'm new to Scala && InteliJ && PlayFramework so i have created template from activator that has generated some play/scala code and templates.

for example one in file views/index.scala.html

```
@play20.welcome(message, style = "Java")
```

How can I locate in which package is this template, and see available templates? I tried right click && reference, GoTo -> Declatration but it showed nothing ?

Comment: I dont think if there are some other template available on default project? It is the only default view that is provided by play

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Play comes with some basic template tags you can use, they are all located here:
http://github.com/playframework/playframework/tree/2.5.4/framework/src/play/src/main/scala/views

As you can see `@play20.welcome(...)` is inside the `play20` folder.
You may find the tags inside the `helper` (for html forms) and `defaultpages` interesting.

However I would recommend you to read the Play Framework documentation, specially the part about templates: https://www.playframework.com/documentation/2.5.x/JavaTemplates

Throughout the documentation actually all the template tags play comes with will be mentioned somewhere - and how to use them in which cases.

**Tip**: In case you want to use Bootstrap there is an awesome library for the Play Framework which comes with all Bootstrap related tags you need: https://adrianhurt.github.io/play-bootstrap/